# Why I separate then mix the channels of one audio file, the speed changed? What I did wrong?

Tags: vb.net, naudio

I'm new to sound programing. For my new project, to simulate 3d sound sources, I need to separate the channels first, then change the volume or delay or something.

But, if I mix the separated channels, the audio speed up! Did I missed something?

this is the code:

```
Imports NAudio.Wave
Imports NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders

Public Class Form1
    Dim n As New WaveOutEvent
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim r = New AudioFileReader("G:\t1\3.wav")

        Dim blst As List(Of MultiplexingWaveProvider) = New List(Of MultiplexingWaveProvider)
        For i = 0 To r.WaveFormat.Channels - 1
            Dim b = New MultiplexingWaveProvider(New IWaveProvider() {r}, 1)
            b.ConnectInputToOutput(i, 0)
            blst.Add(b)
        Next

        Dim bd = New MultiplexingWaveProvider(blst, blst.Count)
        For i = 0 To blst.Count - 1
            bd.ConnectInputToOutput(i, i)
        Next

        n.Init(bd)
        n.Play()
        'speed up
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim r = New AudioFileReader("G:\t1\3.wav")

        Dim blst As List(Of MultiplexingWaveProvider) = New List(Of MultiplexingWaveProvider)
        For i = 0 To r.WaveFormat.Channels - 1
            Dim b = New MultiplexingWaveProvider(New IWaveProvider() {r}, 1)
            b.ConnectInputToOutput(i, 0)
            blst.Add(b)
        Next

        Dim panlist As List(Of ISampleProvider) = New List(Of ISampleProvider)
        For i = 0 To blst.Count - 1
            Dim b = New PanningSampleProvider(blst(i).ToSampleProvider())
            b.Pan = -1 + ((i + 1) * (2 / (blst.Count + 1)))

            'panlist.Add(b.Skip(New TimeSpan(0, 0, i)))
            panlist.Add(b)
        Next

        Dim m1 = New MixingSampleProvider(panlist)

        n.Init(m1)
        n.Play()
        'speed up
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        Dim r = New AudioFileReader("G:\t1\3.wav")

        Dim blst As List(Of MultiplexingWaveProvider) = New List(Of MultiplexingWaveProvider)
        For i = 0 To r.WaveFormat.Channels - 1
            Dim b = New MultiplexingWaveProvider(New IWaveProvider() {r}, 1)
            b.ConnectInputToOutput(i, 0)
            blst.Add(b)
        Next

        n.Init(blst(1))
        n.Play()
        ' original speed
    End Sub
End Class
```

Someone can help?
thanks!

*I realised that here is a better place to ask, so I closed the issue I opened on github yesterday and copy the text then repost to here.

Comment: If you find the solution to your own question please add it as answer and don't edit your question

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution... Just reread the file. Maybe there's a better way. I don't know.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim r = New AudioFileReader("G:\t1\3.wav")

        Dim blst As List(Of MultiplexingWaveProvider) = New List(Of MultiplexingWaveProvider)
        For i = 0 To r.WaveFormat.Channels - 1
            Dim b = New MultiplexingWaveProvider(New IWaveProvider() {r}, 1)
            b.ConnectInputToOutput(i, 0)
            blst.Add(b)

            'added code
            If i < r.WaveFormat.Channels - 1 Then
                r = New AudioFileReader("G:\t1\3.wav")
            End If
            'added code

        Next

        Dim bd = New MultiplexingWaveProvider(blst, blst.Count)
        For i = 0 To blst.Count - 1
            bd.ConnectInputToOutput(i, i)
        Next

        n.Init(bd)
        n.Play()
End Sub
```

I think there would be a better solution than read a file multiple times.